# Have same scaling for multiple Y Axes in Highstock chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to have 2 Y Axes with different heights (80% and 20%) but have the same scaling. Similar to the chart shown below.

[image]

Both Y Axes have exact same scaling. I want to achieve the same thing with Highstock. I tried options like "linkedTo", setting min and max on y-axes. But the closest I could get is what shown below:

[image]

It has the same scaling but has the following issues:

1. First Y Axis had to start with -50 which has no use as real points are starting from 0.
2. Second Y Axis is starting from 50 and ending with -50 which has really no use because values are in range -5 to 0 only.
3. It also loses the ability to auto set extremes when moving the scrollbar at the bottom.

This really makes the chart not very useful. It also breaks if I divide the height into 80%-20% ratio.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goforgold/rgubx4y7/80/)

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
  yAxis: [{
    height: '50%',
    max: 100,
    min: -5,
  }, {
    top: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    linkedTo: 0,
    max: 100,
    min: -5,
  }],
  
  series: [{
    data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  }, {
    data: [0, -1, 0, -2, -2, -3, -2, -5, 0, -2],
    yAxis: 1,
  }],
  
});
```

The chart I am looking at may look something like the below. **Please note that tick lines from 10 to 190 are not appearing in the chart below because of no data falling in this range. But scaling is the same except from point 0 to 200 which I can live with as there is no data in this range.**

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Hi @shashwat, Could you explain your problem in more details? I have tested your example and every point seems to be visible.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. I have added two screenshots for the problem. But my problem have evolved a bit more now with my tries. I will add more details in a few hours. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I have re-described my problems in the question. Please take a look when you get a chance.

Comment: Hi @shashwat, Did you consider using only one y-axis? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/do4vuys6/

Comment: @ppotaczek, yes I had but the problem is my first y-axis values usually start from very high (say 10 million) in that case I see all the unnecessary y-axis ticks from 0 to 10 million. Second y-Axis values stays always below 0.

Comment: Hm, I don't think I fully understand. How you want to have the same scaling and so diverse values? Ticks [0, -5] for the first y-axis and [0, ..., 10 000 000] for the second?

Comment: @ppotaczek example ranges can be as for first y-axis [10M, ...., 15M]. Second y-axis [0, ..., -2M]

Comment: Hi @shashwat, So by the same scaling you meant same distance between ticks? Something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fagk8wv7/ ?

Comment: @ppotaczek I meant same distance but also the difference should be same. For example, in the fiddle you mentioned is `[-6, 0, 25. 50, ..]` but what I need here is `[-25, 0, 25, 50, ...]`

Comment: Hello @shashwat, Sorry for the late reply! II think that using one y-axis and `tickPositioner` function can resolve your problem. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x7f4jepw/

Comment: @ppotaczek I modified the data in your script to relate with my problem. You will see that the tickers from position 0 to 400 are just wastage of screen. And due to this, chart lines appearing close to straight lines. Is there a way that we could better use the space so the up/downs in chart could be more visible? https://jsfiddle.net/goforgold/6vn1sq4r/3/

Comment: This is not possible by using the same scale for both series. As I already mentioned, you can use two y-axes with different scale: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fagk8wv7/

Comment: @ppotaczek Having the same scale is a must to interpret the kind of chart I am doing. If I use two axes, then both axes must have the same start and end point which even wastes more space, and also both axes must have the height distributed as 50-50 for both the axes, otherwise, the chart looks broken (overlapping ticker lines). Is there really a no workaround in HighCharts or you think my problem is just too personal?

Comment: the problem is not about Highcharts, I just can't imagine what the chart should look like according to your expectations. Maybe you could create some better visualization?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek! I added a drawing of the chart I am looking at in the question. Can you please take a look when you get a chance?

Comment: Thanks! You definitely need to use breaks. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g9h73eq8/

Comment: Thanks, @ppotaczek. This looks pretty close. Can we remove unused space from 520 to 540 and -20 to -40? Can we make this chart only show the tick lines at `[520, 515, 510, 500, 0, -5, -10, -15]`? This way the movements will be more clearly visible by removing the unused space at the top and the bottom. And, I am also going to need to calculate `tickInterval` and `breaks` calculated manually as data is going to be dynamic. This is just a sample data resembling my requirements. This is how I tried changing `tickInterval` and `breaks` it http://jsfiddle.net/goforgold/1ozyhx7L/11/

Comment: I thought it over again and it seems that it will be easier to use two y-axes with calculated tick postions. I created this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sy5vrL2k/ - it requires a lot of calculations, so maybe we can still improve it. Please test it.

Comment: Thanks, @ppotaczek for doing this lot of work on my problem. I really feel we are getting real close now. I measured that the distance between horizontal tick lines isn't exactly the same. It is a bit less in the lower y-axis in comparison to the upper y-axis. Can we also not keep the chart height variable? I see that you are using a fixed 600 height.

Comment: I also need this thing implemented in the stock chart with the navigator and also change everything dynamically based on the selected range using the navigator. But, I will try that myself when we have solved the fundamental problem correctly.

Comment: I fixed the mentioned problems here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2atcmjfd/ Will be always negative values on the bottom y-axis?

Comment: Yes, bottom axis will range from `[0 to -n]` or better say `[-n ... 0]`

Comment: I think the solution you provided works well. Let me try to update the same solution with the stock chart while using the same logic on navigation changes. I will let you know if I face any problem.